# Remove first enum value on rails simple_form collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I need help please. How to remove the ":expired" value on simple_form collection?

Here is the code:

```
class ItemExpense < ApplicationRecord
  enum expense_type: [:expired, :damaged, :lost]
end

<%=f.input :expense_type, collection: ItemExpense.expense_types.keys.to_a.map {|i| [i.titleize, i]}, as: :radio_buttons %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may just create a class method

```
class ItemExpense < ApplicationRecord
  enum expense_type: [:expired, :damaged, :lost]
  BLACKLISTED_TYPES = ['expired']

  def self.whitelisted_expense_types
    expense_types.keys - BLACKLISTED_TYPES
  end
end
```

Also, It will be great if you can create a helper method

```
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper
  def whitelisted_expense_types
    ItemExpense.whitelisted_expense_types.map {|i| [i.titleize, i]}
  end
end
```

and use it in views

```
<%= f.input :expense_type, collection: whitelisted_expense_types, as: :radio_buttons %>
```